# What are cam slide adjusters?

Tags: audi, a4, quattro

I am replacing the timing chains and guides. All the data refers to the use of cam pins. Other sources say these pins are used for basic setting of cam slide adjuster?

The car is an Audi A4 2.0 Turbo Quattro

Comment: The only pin I see a reference to is the cam chain tensioner pin. Can you cite a source for the "cam slide adjuster"? Also, what's the year?

Comment: What is your actual question??